# How to copy members with same names in different Structures?

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

I have two different structures. Both have some members of same type & name.

How can I copy all those matching members all at once?

```
struct a{ int i, int j};
struct b{ int j, int k};
```

I wanna perform `a=b`, kind of operation, where `b.j` get copied into `a.j`.
Like wise, how any such matching members should get copied?

Comment: `memcpy(&a, &b, sizeof(a));`?

Comment: @Cyclone, "I have two __different__ structures. Both have __some__ members of same type & name." I think that means they are not exactly the same (whats the point of having 2 exactly same structs anyway?)

Comment: Write a function to copy from a to b. In C++, you could call that function a::operator=

Comment: @Cyclone memcpy will not work; he's interested in copying only certain members, not the whole data structure

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall - Oh, I thought it said `same`.

Comment: Made the same reading mistake :/

Comment: @satya There is no general good way to copy data structure members with the same name between data structures; as far as the compiler is concerned, there is no such thing, it identifies each data member by a different, regenerated name.

Answer (score 3):

Just make an assignment operator, and copy everything you want there

```
struct a{ int i; int j; };
struct b{ 
void operator=(const a & other)
{
    j = other.j;
}
int j; 
int k;
};
```

Then you can just write

```
a one;
b two;
two = one;
```

Answer (score 3):

Since there is some set of matching members of the same type maybe the solution is to pack them together to common type.

```
struct c{ int i, int j};
struct a{ c common, int k, int l, ..., double u};
struct b{ c common, int a, int b, ..., float u, int v};

a one;
b two;

one.common = two.common;
```

If it is impossible because you cannot change the code this way, then I would suggest to write some copy function, but not assignment operator because some time later you or someone else may and probably will use that assignment incorrectly, thinking that it copies all members.

```
void copySharedMembersOfAB( a&, a const& b)
{
    a.i = b.i;
    a.j = b.j;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, but you could improve the clarity be renaming the members of `struct a` and `struct b` (other than `common`) so that they do not correspond either with each other or with members of `struct c`.